# Nudge mouse with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, menu, cursor

I have a link on a page in my site that has to cause the main menu to open as if someone was hovering over one of the menu items. I got that to work no problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a#view-products').on('click', function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1149) {

  //FOR DESKTOP 
        $('ul.mainmenu li.menu.heading.item122.parent.level1').mouseover();
    }

    //FOR MOBILE 
    else{
          $('.mobilebarmenutitle').click();
          $('.item122 > .mobilemenucktogglericon').click();
         }
    });
});
```

The only problem is that the hover state of the main menu item is not activating. It only shows if I nudge the mouse just 1 pixel. At that time the cursor is recognized as being over the menu and the hover state is activated.

Is there any way to nudge the cursor 1px with jQuery? All I can find are ways to move the cursor through text. Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong and there's another way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `.trigger("mouseenter")` (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)).

---

Alternatively (and even more simply), you can trigger a jQuery event by calling its event handler.

For example, if you want to activate the `hover` event, then just do `.mouseenter()` (the first event of a jQuery `.hover()`) on the event you want to hover over.

If you look at the docs, `.mouseenter()`:

> This method is a shortcut for ... `.trigger( "mouseenter" )` in the third.

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave have been what I have used in the past and have helped especially with regards to menu states and have worked well

Comment: @vandsh Yup, they are.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I tried .mouseenter() and .trigger("mouseenter"); and it works the same. The dropdown shows, but the actual menu item still requires the mouse to move before it's highlighted.

Comment: @danzo Do you mean a CSS hover state? I was assuming you meant a jQuery hover event. If so, that could be why.

Comment: @Jonathan - Is it possible to add :hover to an element with jQuery? I was under the impression that it's not?

Comment: I solved it by adding a hover function to addClass jqHover to the original class which simulates :hover, then remove it when the mouse leaves. That works fine. Thanks for the help!